# Angular Bootstrap popover only works once

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a popover which is working fine the first time I use it but then, it's like it needs to be `$compile` again. I'm stuck, I don't what I should do. After it worked properly the first time, then trying to click on the button inside the popover has no effect at all.

My html:

```
<button blockpopover templatepk="template.pk" class="btn">
    Add block
</button>
```

The popovertemplate html:

```
<div id="popoverblock">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="createBlock('Basic');">Basic</button>
</div>
```

The code called with `createBlock()` executes nicely and returns without error. (An object block is created)

My directive:

```
app.directive('blockpopover', function ($templateCache) {

    var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
        var template = '';
        switch (contentType) {
            case 'createBlock':
                template = $templateCache.get("templatePopoverBlock.html");
                break;
        }
        return template;
    }
    return {
        scope:{'templatepk': '='},
        restrict: "A",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $compile, $timeout){
            $scope.createBlock = function (type) {
                var type = type;
                $scope.$parent.createBlock($scope.templatepk, type);
                // use the parent scope function
            };
            var popOverContent;
            content = getTemplate("createBlock");
            popOverContent = $compile(content)($scope);
            var options = {
                trigger: 'focus',
                content: popOverContent,
                placement: "bottom",
                html: true,
            };
            $element.popover(options);
        }
     };
});
```

Comment: did you find solution how to fix that?

Comment: The requirement changed, i switched to something else. Do you have the same issue?

Comment: Yes. I had to switch to angular-strap popover to fix this problem. Now it solved.